# How to resize an image on preview (no database)

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, resize

I have script to preview input type=file (image), and generate it into pdf.

There's no problem for a small size of image. Then when i input with size 6Mb, the preview is OK, but when generate to pdf, its take very long time and finally stopped.

So, I want to resize the image size to 200x240px. But i don't know how to do it, because the script using javascript and I still newbie on it.

Please help how to resize it on my script.

Script:

```
  function previewFile(){
   var preview = document.querySelector('img'); //selects the query named img
   var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]; //sames as here
   var reader  = new FileReader();

   reader.onloadend = function () {
     console.log(reader.result);
       //preview.src = reader.result;
       $('#gen-template-frame').contents().find('.logo img').attr('src', reader.result);
   }

   if (file) {
       reader.readAsDataURL(file); //reads the data as a URL
   } else {
       preview.src = "";
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/magang/front.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="corpname" contenteditable>RUMAH SAKIT HARUM</div>
    <div class="logosisma"><img src="https://sismadigroup.com/idcard/images/background/logo-id-card.png" width="219" height="70" /></div>
    <div class="logo">
        <!--<img src="resize/resize.php?src=https://sismadigroup.com/idcard/templates/images/avatar/3.jpg&scale=10&q=100">-->
        <img src="https://sismadigroup.com/idcard/templates/images/avatar/3.jpg" width="200" height="240" />
    </div>
    <div class="name highlight" contenteditable>Maesyaroh</div>
    <div class="position" contenteditable>Siswa Magang</div>
    <div class="nik" contenteditable>SM-0035</div>
    <div class="BBP">BENAR &nbsp; BAIK &nbsp; PANTAS</div>
    <div class="BBPPoint" style="left:135px;"> . </div>
    <div class="BBPPoint" style="left:203px;"> . </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: PHP for PDF generation:

```
$frontPage = resolveDependency(stripslashes( $_POST[ "html" ] ));
$backPage = resolveDependency(stripslashes( $_POST[ "html2" ]) );
$frontPageCSS = getCSSFromHTML($frontPage);
$backPageCSS = getCSSFromHTML($backPage);
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', array(75, 114.6), 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($frontPageCSS, 1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($frontPage, 0);
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak>', 2);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($backPageCSS, 1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($backPage, 0);
$mpdf->Output('card.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: I don't think that you can't do that with JS, but maybe you can do it on the server side. How are you generating the PDF?

Comment: `$frontPage = resolveDependency(stripslashes( $_POST[ "html" ] ));
 $backPage = resolveDependency(stripslashes( $_POST[ "html2" ]) );

 $frontPageCSS = getCSSFromHTML($frontPage);
 $backPageCSS = getCSSFromHTML($backPage);

 $mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', array(75, 114.6), 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($frontPageCSS, 1);
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($frontPage, 0);
 $mpdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak>', 2);
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($backPageCSS, 1);
 $mpdf->WriteHTML($backPage, 0);
 $mpdf->Output('card.pdf', 'I');`

Comment: i use script like that

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using PHP to generate the PDF you can resize the image with PHP before using it with `mPDF`. I don't see in your code how you load the image, so I suppose that you use the [`Image()`](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/image.html) function for loading the image from a file (in this example `$fileName` is the name of the input image, replace it with the variable that you use in your code):

```
// $fileName is the name of the input image
list($width,$height)=getimagesize($fileName); // size of input image
$tempFileName=tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),"img").".png";
$newWidth=200;
$newHeight=240;

$image=imagecreatefrompng($fileName); // load the input image
$newImage=imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth,$newHeight); //create an empty image
imagecopyresampled($newImage,$image,0,0,0,0,$newWidth,$newHeight,$width,$height);
imagepng($newImage,$tempFileName,9); // saving the new image to disk

// here you create the PDF using the image saved in $tempFileName

unlink($tempFileName); // and finally we delete the temporal file
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem on front-end, before uploading file. You can visit [a link](https://diyazy.github.io/image-square-resizer/)!

```
import imageSqResizer from './image-square-resizer.js'

let resizer = new imageSqResizer(
    'image-input',
    300,
    (dataUrl) => 
        document.getElementById('image-output').src = dataUrl;
);
//Get blob
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('files[0]', resizer.blob);

//get dataUrl
document.getElementById('image-output').src = resizer.dataUrl;
```